# Connecting SQL Server from Eclipse throws TLSv1 SSLContext not available

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, tls1.0

I need to connect to an old SQL Server from Eclipse.

First, an error complaining about TLS10 not being supported, so I looked here and there and edited *java.security* and now looks like:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \  
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \  
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

That made the error disappear but another one now claims:

`TLSv1 SSLContext not available`

Again, I searched here and there and found something about *jsee.jar*. It´s hard to find it, but I finally got it, but here's the actions I´ve taken and the error persists.

- copied the file in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\lib"
- copied a file I found jsse-1.0.8.jar to the same location and renamed it to
  jsee.jar
- installed the latest JDK

The complete error messages is:

```
El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL). 
Error: "TLSv1 SSLContext not available". ClientConnectionId:something
  TLSv1 SSLContext not available
  TLSv1 SSLContext not available
```

The Eclipse version is

```
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 18.0.2.1+1-1
Java version: 18.0.2.1
```

How can I solve this? Please no "update your server" solutions. I have not any control over it, and in fact, I don´t even know where is it.

***Edit*** I also need to connect from excel and that runs fine. It's clear that's because true binary code and java interpreted code are two different worlds

Comment: How are you connecting to sql server and what kind of driver are you using? Perhaps you can disable TLS altogether, but that depends on the driver. Oh yeah, almost forgot, you should really upgrade your sql server

Comment: The server insists on using TLSed 1.0 connections. I use the JDBC driver Eclipse provided. By the way, I have other machine that connected fine after modifying java.security. I´m still trying to find differences between them. Unfortunately it's not my server is someone "that's the machine, deal with it but don't touch it" server

Comment: Jars internal to the JRE/JDK usually aren't swappable like this. They may tie into natives that are particular to that version of the vendor's JVM. If you need a different jsee.jar, you need a different Java runtime. TLS v1 has been disabled since Java 11.

How is Eclipse involved?

Comment: @nitind but why it was not initially installed? JDK 18.0.2.1 is not that old, and the latest version (21), didn't copy jsee.jar neither

Comment: Ok, but how does your jdbc url look?

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=example.com\SQLEXPRESS;port=5925;databaseName=thename
Note: the other (desktop) machine has exactly the same url and connects fine

Comment: What happens if you add `;encrypt=false`

Comment: same result @siggemannen. It seems the server only accepts TLS 1.0 connections

Comment: Strange, that option should disable ssl altogether. If you run wireshark, do you see SSL negotiation going on from your client

Comment: Sounds like the DBAs have enabled the Force Encryption option on the target instance, i.e.: SQL Server [version] Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for [instance name] > Properties > Force Encryption = Yes | No.

Comment: I know you asked for no "update your server" solutions, but it really is the best way. And you already know that. It's counter-productive to hobble and compromise the security of modern tools and libraries to work with old and unpatched servers. You really should encourage the server's DBAs to apply the latest service packs and cumulative updates, ref: [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server).

Comment: I won't publish it as a solution since I don't want a down vote answer to my (I don´t know why) down voted question. I installed the last JDK (22) and it connected smoothly. Digging in the net I found that the "TLSv1 SSLContext not available" error is more less common (not just for SQL Sever) and the "solution" is to reinstall (or upgrade) the JDK. It seems that for some reason, it gets corrupted or files are "lost" (I had to apply java.security patch to the newly installed JDK)